# Finding remainders progressively

Tags: algorithm, math

I have a number say 345691. I want to find remainders in backward direction.Say :

```
first_remainder=1%b
second_remainder=91%b
third_remainder=691%b
fourth_remainder=5691%b
.
.
.
last_remainder=345691%9;
```

I came across following formulation:

```
current_remainder = (currentdigit * P +previous_remainder) % b; P=10^(lenght ofnumber-1)
```

I tried understanding but could not understand the roots of this formulation. Can some one help me understand why it works ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
345691 => 1 + 9*10 + 6*100 + 5*1000 + 4 *10000 + 3*100000
```

that's probably the simplest way you can correlate the formulation. Further more, to relate more variables -

```
=> 1*10^0 + 9*10^1 + 6*10^2 + 5*10^3 + 4*10^4 + 3*10^5

=> ....... + 3*10^(number.length -1)
```

Comment: you mean spliiting based on (a1 + a2 + a3 + a4 + ... + an) modx = (a1 mod x + a2 mod x + a3 mod x + ... + an mod x) mod x ?

Comment: [Yes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation)....`(a + b) mod n = [(a mod n) + (b mod n)] mod n.`

Comment: but for this case , does following hold true as well ? : (a + b) mod n = [(a mod n) + (b)] mod n .... bit weak at modular mathematics :) ie  [(1 mod n) + (9*10)] mod n

Comment: @danishsodhi in the statement in answer, try and place `modn`(for your example `%b`) at both sides of expression and that should help you understand as you expand the expression further

Comment: :Thanks alot ,that helped me understand !

Comment: @danishsodhi Cool, if it did. Do mark it as an answer for future readers. :)

Comment: My last question : is  (a + b) % n == ((a%n) + (b%x)) % n same as (a + b) % x == ((a%x) + b) % x . For this case  (1 + 9*10) % n == ((1%x) + 9*10) % n

Comment: `(1 + 9*10) % n` ==> `((1%n) + ((9*10) % n)) %n`

Comment: Then the correct formulation should be : current_remainder = (previous_remainder+(currentdigit * P )%b) % b; No ?

Comment: @danishsodhi there is an overall modulus, so its already implemented  (currentdigit * P +previous_remainder) % b ==> `(currentdigit*P%b) + previous_remainder%b` .....Also note the rule `(a mod n) mod n = a mod n.`